# demerits of median of medians approach in choosing pivot for QUICKSORT

Tags: pivot, quicksort

-randomized approach does not guarantee better space time complexity.

-choosing median as pivot guarantees the best space time complexity,same as that of merge sort.(also making quicksort better than merge sort as quicksort is easier to code)

and yet people always teach to use the randomized approach to pick a pivot, even though it is the worst option among the above two approaches.

why?

Comment: Although [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) limits the worst case time complexity to O(n log(n)), it's significantly slower in the average case (the constant for the time complexity is larger). If you have the space, merge sort is significantly quicker than using quick sort with median of medians.